# Run meteor.js apps in android studio inside ubuntu in virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization, android-studio

I am following the `meteor.js` todo list app tutorial. I'm at the section where it describes how to run on mobile.
The problem is, according to the tutorial, I can't do this on a Windows system.

So I installed `virtualbox`, then installed `ubuntu 18.04`. I have the acceleration settings below.

[image]

I then installed `Android studio`. I installed SDK Platform for Android 8.0 (API level 26) and under SDK Tools I installed Android Emulator.

I now open Android studio's AVD Manager to create a virtual device. But no matter which image I select I get the message `Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM).

CPU-Z reports that my PC supports VT-x and I have virtualization enabled in my Bios

[image]

**I want to know if its actually possible to run android studio inside ubuntu in virtualbox (and how).**

*Aside: Is there another way to test meteor apps for android?*